# console Proxy which keeps line numbers, has prefix AND respects string substitution

Tags: javascript, console.log

I've created a `console` Proxy which right now doesn't do much more than adding a prefix on each line written to the console, and it works perfectly, even keeps line numbers intact (that is, the messages have the proper origin shown by the browser). Here is the code:

```
const disabledMethodsInProduction = ['debug', 'log', 'trace'];
logger = new Proxy(console, {
    get (target, method) {
        if (method in target) {
            if (!developmentMode && disabledMethodsInProduction.includes(method)) {
                return () => { /* NOP */ };
            }
            // 'loggingID' is a string, defined elsewhere.
            return target[method].bind(console, `${loggingID}:`);
        }
        throw new Error(`Method '${method}()' not implemented in console.`);
    }
});
```

The problem with the above code is the **same** that other solutions that I've investigated (and commented) here in Stack Overflow. To wit, the prefix (in this case, the `loggingID` string) is now the **FIRST** argument of the `console` object method, so when calling the proxy object above with a message containing string substitutions (`%c` for example), they won't be processed because they are now the **SECOND** argument instead.

The fix is easy: instead of returning the `console` method, a new function can be returned which traps the arguments provided and if the first one is a string and contains string substitutions, the prefix is inserted in *that* argument, instead of being a different argument:

```
return function () {
    // Do things with 'arguments' and pass it to the proper console method.
    const args = Array.from(arguments);
    // Yes, I know, first I should check args[0] to see
    // if it is a string and contains string substitutions.
    args[0] = `${loggingID}: ` + args[0];
    target[method](...args);  // THIS line number will appear in console messages, obviously.
}
```

Unfortunately, doing that clobbers the original line numbers, obviously.

Any solution to have **both** features, that is, keeping line numbers and trapping the arguments at the same time?

I can live with losing the ability of using string substitutions, as keeping line numbers is far more important for me, but I'm just curious about how to solve this, and I would love to have both features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of achieving what I need but requires a set of extra parens:

```
const disabledMethodsInProduction = ['debug', 'log', 'trace'];
logger = new Proxy(console, {
    get (target, method) {
        if (method in target) {
            if (!developmentMode && disabledMethodsInProduction.includes(method)) {
                return () => { /* NOP */ };
            }
            return function (...args) {
                // An additional check for string subtitution chars is needed.
                if (typeof args[0] === 'string') {
                    // 'loggingID' is a string, defined elsewhere.
                    args[0] = `${loggingID}: ${args[0]}`;
                }
                return target[method].bind(console, ...args);
            };
        }
        throw new Error(`Method '${method}()' not implemented in console.`);
    }
});

// Should be used like this:
// logger.log('%cThis is bold', 'font-weight:bold')();
```

Notice the extra pair of parentheses when calling the proxied object method.

This solution:

1. Preserves line numbers, showing those of the caller.
2. Can selectively disabled in production.
3. Honors string substitutions in the first argument.

If anyone has any idea about how getting rid of the ugly extra pair of parentheses, I'm all ears.